# Printing a PDF from a macOS App - Defining the context as a a PDFDocument

Tags: macos, pdf, printing

We are porting from iOS to macOS and need to be able to print PDF documents directly from the app. Below is the relevant method.

Just don't see how to define the "contextInfo" as the PDFDocument?

```
 - (void)printDocumentWithSettings:(NSDictionary<NSPrintInfoAttributeKey, id>   *)printSettings 
               showPrintPanel:(BOOL)showPrintPanel 
                     delegate:(id)delegate 
             didPrintSelector:(SEL)didPrintSelector 
                  contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;

  PDFDocument *pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

Sending our user to the AdobePDF viewer to search through the system folders is not a solution.  As is typical the Apple Doc is not helpful and many of the macOS samples are up to eight years old!

Any help or alternate solution would be appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for using Swift, but this is the approach I've taken for printing PDF.

PDFDocument has a method to create an NSPrintOperation.

```
if let printOperation = thePDFDocument?.printOperation(for: thePrintInfo(), scalingMode: .pageScaleNone, autoRotate: true){
            printOperation.printPanel = thePrintPanel()
            /// Would prefer to use .runModal but don't know what the window is.
            printOperation.run()
        }
```

thePrintInfo() and thePrintPanel() are functions that define the print settings and dialog.

```
func thePrintInfo() -> NSPrintInfo {
        let thePrintInfo = NSPrintInfo()
        thePrintInfo.horizontalPagination = .fit
        thePrintInfo.verticalPagination = .fit
        thePrintInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
        thePrintInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
        thePrintInfo.leftMargin = 0.0
        thePrintInfo.rightMargin = 0.0
        thePrintInfo.topMargin = 0.0
        thePrintInfo.bottomMargin = 0.0
        thePrintInfo.jobDisposition = .spool
        return thePrintInfo
    }

    // Add the Page Setup options to the Print Dialog
    func thePrintPanel() -> NSPrintPanel {
        let thePrintPanel = NSPrintPanel()
        thePrintPanel.options = [
            NSPrintPanel.Options.showsCopies,
            NSPrintPanel.Options.showsPrintSelection,
            NSPrintPanel.Options.showsPageSetupAccessory,
            NSPrintPanel.Options.showsPreview
        ]
        return thePrintPanel
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code benwiggy.  This is a great example of how it takes 20 lines of swift code to accomplish what can be done in three lines of Objective C code!

Comment: To be fair, I think it would probably be similar in ObjC: you don't have to set all those paramters, and the OS will use the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by:

Creating a pdfView.

```
 @property (weak) IBOutlet PDFView *showPDFView;
```

Assigning the URL of your PDF and setting the view to this document.

```
 pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:url];

 [showPDFView setDocument:pdfDoc];
```

Calling the print method on the view.

```
 [showPDFView print : nil];
```

That's all there is to it!

Comment: Printing the PDFView is not the same as printing the PDF data itself. You can end up with scroll bars on your printout!